# How do log files work properly?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Tried researching but hit a dead end.

In Java (or any other language), how do logging to a file work - more specifically:

- How does the file not get locked when another event occurs and needs to be logged?
- Is there a queue for appending to the log file?
- If the file is not locked, how do log entries get mixed up? E.g. one error stream being logged while another is still being written?
- Can the file be opened or written by another process without interrupting a logging activity?

Comment: Question is "too broad", since 1) you're asking 4 questions, not one, and 2) answers depend on the logging implementation you're using. Some support queuing and asynchronous writes, **if you configure them** for it.

Comment: Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

> How does the file not get locked when another event occurs and needs to be logged?

No. In memory locking occurs, but the file itself is not locked and cannot be shared across processes.

> Is there a queue for appending to the log file?

Only if you use an asynchronous appender.

> If the file is not locked, how do log entries get mixed up? E.g. one error stream being logged while another is still being written?

A regular Java lock.

> Can the file be opened or written by another process without interrupting a logging activity?

It can be opened but if you write to it from another process you can lose data.  This not not how a log file is intended to be used.